# Nodejs app throws E11000 duplicate key error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

When I enter data on the webpage, the data syncs to the database correctly.
But when i try to fill the same form again it gives an error :

```
{
    "code": 11000,
    "index": 0,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.creates index: aname_1 dup key: { : \"MicroSoft\" }",
    "op": {
        "aname":"MicroSoft",
        "pname":"Bing",
        "pusername":"Debtanu",
        "_id":"57c9486d690a35fc21794169",
        "__v":0
    }
}
```

After deleting every thing from DB and trying again to fill the same form, it takes the entry.
Then why is it not taking the next entry to the same Account form??

Below is my app.js and Account.jade file .

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
 var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
 var path = require('path');
 var logger = require('morgan');
 var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var session = require('express-session')
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
 var passport = require('passport');
 var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
 var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
 var async = require('async');
 var crypto = require('crypto');
 var flash = require('express-flash');
 var router = express.Router();
 var fs = require('fs');


var createSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cname: {type: String, unique: true, sparse: true},
    aname : {type: String, unique: true, sparse: true},
    ausername : String,
    pname : {type: String, unique: true, sparse: true},
    pusername : String
});


var Create = mongoose.model('Create', createSchema);

mongoose.connect('localhost');

var app = express();


// Middleware
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret:'keyboard cat',
    // connect-mongo session store
    proxy: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/public')));
app.use('/img',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images')));




app.get('/Account', function(req, res) {
    res.render('Account', {
        user: req.user 
    });
});

app.post('/Account', function(req,res,next){
    var create = new Create({
        cname: req.body.cname,
        aname: req.body.aname,
        ausername: req.body.ausername
    });

    create.save(function(err, doc){
        if(err) res.json(err)
        else res.redirect('/home');
    });
});

// Server
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

*account.jade is not in the suitable format*

Comment: The Create Schema is the schema to declare the Account variables. And I feel that there is some issue with the next() function, but dont know how to add it correctly.

Comment: Please format your app.js so that it is readable, with clear indents. I have done the JSON error message to show you how it should look. Maybe also just post the section relevant to this question.

Comment: In any case you have a duplicate key error, it looks like aname is your primary key and you are trying to create two entries with the value of MicroSoft.

Comment: Nearly 400lines of **unformatted**, **unindented**, **irrelevant** code is not the way to do. You are supposed to post a *MCVE*, not a dump of your whole project.

Comment: You have unique indexes defined here `aname : {type: String, unique: true, sparse: true}, ...` thus the duplicate error bubbles up to your app since you are trying to save the same data. Either make sure you save distinct data elements on those fields you defined as unique indexes or remove the unique indexes.

Comment: As per the requirement the variable aname has to be unique. My basic point is why the form Account is not taking the next entry. Once the data is entered and saved properly now again if i want to fill the form with some different data then at least it should take the entry, but its not.

Comment: @chridam:   how can I do this "Either make sure you save distinct data elements on those fields you defined as unique indexes "

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared aname as **unique** field in Schema, you could save only unique values in the database. This is the same for cname and pusername.

In your case, when you save MicroSoft for the first time, it saves the document. Whereas, in the next time when you try to save MicroSoft, mongo throws error as the same value is already present in the database.

So as a solution, you should either remove unique condition or you should save only unique values.

Comment: 1) I have a page called Account which gets the info like : a) Cluster name b) Account Name c)User name . 2)there is a second page called Project which gets info like : a)Account name b)Project Name c) username. now Cluster breaks to form Accounts and Accounts further breaks to different Projects. In Accounts page need to save the data like Cluster name and below that cluster a new account. Then to create a new project need to fill the project form with the Account name in which the project will be and the new project name. This is the format. Can someone help to correct the schema.